# Azure Web App + Docker + Linux : server error Host.DestinationHostUrl must be specified

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Seeing the following error on Azure Web App docker container logs :

```
2019-09-10T22:09:56.042029809Z Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Host.DestinationHostUrl must be specified either as an environment variable or as a command-line switch.
2019-09-10T22:09:56.042053010Z    at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.MiddlewareShim.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /EasyAuth/Middleware.Host/Startup.cs:line 51
2019-09-10T22:09:56.042058710Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-09-10T22:09:56.042063211Z    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2019-09-10T22:09:56.042067511Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
2019-09-10T22:09:56.042071811Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
2019-09-10T22:09:56.042076011Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
2019-09-10T22:09:56.043547163Z    at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.MiddlewareShim.Program.Main(String[] args) in /EasyAuth/Middleware.Host/Program.cs:line 27
```

Note that this is running on linux docker image. Not sure if this is an internal issue or something wrong with my docker image. Dockerfile is pretty straight forward :

```
FROM node:lts

# Copying source files
ARG BUILDDIR=.
ADD $BUILDDIR/foo .

# Installing dependencies
RUN npm install

# Building app
RUN npm run build

# Running the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Appreciate any pointers on how to resolve this.

Comment: What do you have at /EasyAuth/Middleware.Host/Startup.cs:line 51, can you please add your Startup.cs

Comment: I don't have any such code in my project. My app is an expressjs app.

Comment: We are getting the same error in our Azure App Service Web App (linux container). This causes our service calls to fail with 403 error. Turning off and turning on App Service Authentication temporarily fixes this. But it appears again. Looks like there is an issue with the EasyAuth container. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#on-containers